# How do websites uniquely identify your computer even with other computers on your network?

Tags: networking, privacy, privacy-protection

There's a site that I visit that shows a captcha every 2 hours or so and I was just wondering how they did it.

NOTE: I am not trying to circumvent it because the rewards of doing so would be next to nothing. I'm just curious as to how they track you.

Even with two computers on the same networks, with both of them on the same account, only one will show the captcha. This would mean that they aren't using your external IP or your account itself to track you

I've tried clearing my cookies as well as changing my user-agent, but nothing changes.

What other methods are there for a site to uniquely identify you?

Comment: The answer is too broad as there are many different possibilities. Its probably a combination of public ip address, cookies, user agent, local time, etc...

Comment: @LPChip Is there any way to block that without slowing down or internet (no TOR)

Comment: Many websites generate [fingerprints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) to uniquely identify each browser.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [cookies](http://www.whatarecookies.com/), your internet connection and browser leak a lot of information. See [IP/DNS Detect](https://ipleak.net/), [SystmDetail.com](http://www.systemdetails.com/index.php), [MyBrowserInfo.com](http://MyBrowserInfo.com) for browser information.

See [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/115483/htg-explains-learn-how-websites-are-tracking-you-online/) for a general discussion.

Comment: If two computers are on the same network, shouldn't all this information be the same? If so, how would a website differentiate between two computers on the same network? Also, the website isn't using user-agents as stated in the post, so I'm still not sure how it's storing data.

Comment: Cookies are per machine and sometimes per user.

Comment: I already cleared the cookies. They still stored the data. That's what originally puzzled me about the whole thing.

Comment: Including Adobe Flash and MS Silverlight cookies? See http://www.wikihow.com/Delete-Flash-Cookies and http://www.thewindowsclub.com/types-of-internet-cookies

Comment: Let me take a look at those.